# Move "Items per page" selector to the top of the content

Tags: views

This is my problem of the day.
I would like to display the Items per page at the top of the content block.

I'm working on a View Block, this is an Exposed Filter with "Better Exposed Filter".
For now, I'm doing this the dirty way with jQuery and a unstable DOMSubtreeModified bind.
I have a twig with {{ exposed }}, but Drupal doesn't suggest me any deeper twig and if I had one, it wouldn't access the Content div I guess. So I have no idea about how to do this.

Here is the div organisation :

- div.exposed-block
  - form.views-exposed-form
    - Filter-1
    - Filter-2
    - **Items-per-page** (select)
- **div.view-block** (with my content)

So, the idea is to move **Items-per-page** to **div.view-block**.
Or into another that I can create, here is the twig part :

```
<div class="exposed-block">
    {{ exposed }}
</div>

<div class="bmcp-view-block">
    {{ rows }}
</div>
```

How would you do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I got from a forum.

```
<div class="exposed-block">
    {{ exposed | without ('items_per_page') }}
</div>

<div class="view-block">
    {{ exposed | without('my_first_other_filter', 'my_second_other_filter') }}
    {{ rows }}
</div>
```